# Magento Unsupported operand types issue

Tags: php, magento

I've the following issue in Magento. Now i've added the function that i've this issue with.

> Fatal error: Unsupported operand types in
>   /var/www/html/app/code/core/Mage/Wishlist/Model/Item.php on line 431

```
public function getBuyRequest()
{
    $option = $this->getOptionByCode('info_buyRequest');
    $initialData = $option ? unserialize($option->getValue()) : null;

    // There can be wrong data due to bug in Grouped products - it formed 'info_buyRequest' as Varien_Object
    if ($initialData instanceof Varien_Object) {
        $initialData = $initialData->getData();
    }

    $buyRequest = new Varien_Object($initialData);
    $buyRequest->setOriginalQty($buyRequest->getQty())
        ->setQty($this->getQty() * 1);
    return $buyRequest;
}
```

Comment: What is this for ?

$this->getQty() * 1

Comment: @CntkCtn In Magento decimal values like qtys and prices are stored as strings. `*1` coerces them to int or float, depending on what they represent.

Comment: Have you solved this issue? I faced with it too.